# Как задать свойство последнему наследнику последнего наследника?

Tags: css

Имеется такая структура:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо задать некоторые свойства тегу  последнего  в блоке .

Comment: `#breadcrumbs span:last-child a`

Comment: так ведь это всем спанам, а мне нужно последнему.

Comment: @Anhk, нет, это ссылка для последнего

Comment: И да, ваш код не будет работать, потому что вы использовали больше чем одно одинаковое айди

Comment: код находится на этапе отладки, т.ч. этот момент будет исправлен.
всем спасибо,- Grundy прав.

Comment: @Niklex, код работать будет, просто возможно не совсем так как ожидалось :)

Comment: а вам еще и последний `a` нужен в последнем `span`?

Comment: нет, только ссылка в последнем спане дива.

Comment: @Anhk, псевдо-класс last-child - как раз и говорит брать последний

Comment: я думал, что это будет вот так примерно:
#breadcrumbs:last-child.

Comment: @Anhk, этот селектор выберет  `#breadcrumbs` если он будет последним элементом на уровне. если вам нужно выбрать `a` - то такой селектор не поможет, кроме того, если используется несколько одинаковых `id` выберется только первый, так как id  должны быть уникальны на странице

Answer (score 1):

`#breadcrumbs > span:last-child > a:last-child`